# how do i make this NOT a loop?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

how can i make this NOT a loop?

```
             {
             ManagementObjectSearcher Vquery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
             ManagementObjectCollection Vcoll = Vquery.Get();
             foreach (ManagementObject mo in Vcoll)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + mo["name"].ToString());
             }
```

Comment: What's wrong with having a loop?

Comment: cause it opens the page twice.

Comment: @NightsEvil - and you wanted it to do what? (assuming there are multiple controllers). If the problem is multiple pages, why not ask "how do I stop this opening multiple pages?"

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Win32_VideoController`

Comment: Can't you just add a `break` (not a C# programmer here)?

Comment: If  you don't want a loop, don't use foreach. Does Vcoll hold only 1 managements object or 2 the same?

Comment: I don't get this question. Surely if you're doing something twice, and don't want to do it twice, stop doing it? Grab the first item from the collection and process that and you're done. What am I not getting here?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: From what I can see, it is difficult to access a single object of the collection directly.

Comment: yea i just want the page to come up ONCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very stupid code to avoid foreach:

```
if( Vcoll.Count > 0)
{
   IEnumerator en = collection.GetEnumerator();
   en.MoveNext();
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + en.Current["name"].ToString());
}
```

But, if the problem is opening multiple pages, I'd prefer a simple break in the foreach:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in Vcoll)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + mo["name"].ToString());
   break;
}
```

Comment: totally what i needed was a break; thank you so much! i feel pretty retarded... lol thanks any ways

Comment: sometimes, all you need is a break - sounds like ancient wisdom

Comment: That is *not* a complete/correct `IEnumerator` usage; you should also check for `IDisposable` and call `Dispose()`. Or better; just use `foreach` with `break`.

Comment: @Marc: you're right, mine was a sort of provocation not a real solution to adopt (foreach is far clear) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
var procs = (from mo in (new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController")).Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                    select (System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + mo["name"].ToString()))).ToList();
```

Comment: No; the execution in LINQ is deferred. That doesn't actually *do* anything except set up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few (fairly pointless) ways involving lists and methods like `ForEach` - or possibly `Select`, but you aren't solving a problem here. Just use the loop. It expresses perfectly what you are doing.

One hacky way (I **don't** recommmend this here):

```
Vcoll.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(mo =>
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="
        + mo["name"].ToString())).ToArray();
```

**not** an improvement IMO.

Answer (score 0):

A common one-liner is:

```
Vcoll.ForEach( mo -> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + mo["name"].ToString()));
```

Of course ForEach has its own loop inside.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to accomplish is not opening pages twice, then use "distinct":

```
var foundNames = 
  (from ManagementObject mo in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController").Get()
   let name = mo["Name"].ToString()
   where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
   select name).Distinct();

foreach(var name in foundNames)
  Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + name);
```